# I am not able to add form entries to my database

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

**Problem**

I am trying to push username and password entries to my database using following code(named as `application.py` inside my project)

**Code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

application = Flask(__name__)
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///mydtb.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(application)

class Mydtb(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement = True)
    user = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.utcnow)
    def __init__(self, user, password):
        user = self.user
        password = self.password

@application.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    title = 'Registration page'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        record = Mydtb(request.form['usrname'], request.form['pwd'])
        db.session.add(record)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        mydtb = Mydtb.query.order_by(Mydtb.created)
        return render_template('index.html', title=title, mydtb = mydtb)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug = True)
```

I've already generated `.db` file, `html` form is also working fine but it seems `application.py` code is unable to push those form entries to database.

> You can see the error that I am getting from `debug section` , I want to fix it without using extra libraries.

[image: Error message using app.run(debug=True)]

Comment: Your `__init__` looks wrong. Shouldn't it be `self.user = user` and `self.password = password`?

Comment: Yes, you are right **Jeff** thanks for pointing it out, now it works fine. It should be `self.user = user` and `self.password = password`

Comment: Unless you are doing some extra work, you don't actually need to define `__init__` for (flask-)sqlalchemy models: `instance = MyModel(foo=42, bar='spam')` will work out of the box.